# How to set responsive image's max width (Bootstrap 4)?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsiveness

**Question:**

- How do you set the max-width of an image in Bootstrap 4 while retaining the image's responsiveness?

**Background:**

- Boostrap 4's `.img-fluid` class makes images responsive.

> max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/)

**My situation:**

- See **JS Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/290257/
- I have an image that is very big... too big.
- I have set `max-width: 500px` (inline styling), and this sets the image's width - Awesome.
- **Problem**: It does not resize / respond when you shrink the window size... It is no longer responsive.

Hope that was clear; I've tried to look for similar questions here but wasn't successful. Cheers!

Comment: instead of px define the width in percentage say "width=100%;"

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/saravanan7944/ygamjz7s/1/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your answer is here

```
.img-max {
  max-width: 500px;
  width:100%;
}
```

and use the class in the image.

I have edited your fiddle. Please refer the link

[jsfiddle.net/saravanan7944/ygamjz7s/1](https://jsfiddle.net/saravanan7944/ygamjz7s/1)

Answer (score 4):

```css
.img-max {
  max-width: 500px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<p class="alert-primary p-3">
  I can set the max-width of the image... but then it stops being responsive.
</p>
  



<div class="container">
  <div class="img-max">
  <img  class=" mx-auto d-block mb-2 float-md-left mr-md-4 img-thumbnail"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2422/sky-earth-galaxy-universe.jpg">
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore ipsa ea dolorem mollitia repudiandae odit dolore quod et voluptatem asperiores odio quam ipsam placeat nisi quo voluptate, laborum provident earum?
  </p>
</div>
```