# How can I make images responsive height and width in row - bootstrap 4

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm working on a project and I need to display the images the same height in the row column.

Below is my code:

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content adjustment col-lg-6">
            <a href=""><img class="image image1 img-responsive" src="images/assets/one.png" /></a>
            <div class="on_hover">
                <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content adjustment higher col-lg-3">
            <a href=""><img class="image image2 img-responsive" src="images/assets/two.png"
                    style="width:100%;height:80%;" /></a>
            <div class="on_hover">
                <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content adjustment col-lg-3">
            <a href=""><img class="image img-responsive" src="images/assets/three.png" style="width:100%;height:80%;" /></a>
            <div class="on_hover">
                <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Preview of the current website:
[image]

Comment: What is the issue and how does it look like now ( an example preview image can be useful ) ?

Comment: @Emz1402 are you trying to set the height of col-lg-6 img to have the height to cover the height of col-lg-3?

Comment: or if you are trying to set the height of all images same then try set a specific height for all 3 images and also try to use max-height if needed it will be not exceed the width because of img-responsive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set responsive image's max width (Bootstrap 4)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721711/how-to-set-responsive-images-max-width-bootstrap-4)

Comment: sorry i added the a preview of current image row.

Comment: i need to align the height of image 2 and image 3 to image 1..

Comment: my pleasure, And if you are using bootstrap 4 then you should use img-fluid bcz img-responsive doesn't work in bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="content adjustment col-lg-6">
        <a href=""><img class="image image1 img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" style="width:100%;height:auto;" /></a>
        <div class="on_hover">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content adjustment higher col-lg-3">
        <a href=""><img class="image image2 img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
                style="width:100%;height:auto;" /></a>
        <div class="on_hover">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content adjustment col-lg-3">
        <a href=""><img class="image img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%;height:auto;" /></a>
        <div class="on_hover">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Check here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G0ZT64GJSXU6)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **img-responsive** to **img-fluid**.

In bootstrap 3 we used `img-responsive` for the responsive image but is is changed in bootstrap 4.